# Using Spark to insert into Hive database with "." in database name

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code to select some data from a Hive table, do some simple transformations, then insert them back into the same table:

```scala
sqlContext.sql("USE `database.with.dot`");
val ds = sqlContext.sql("select * from Table where column = 'SomeValue'");
ds.withColumn("anotherColumn", lit("SomeOtherValue"))
  .write.insertInto("Table")
```

However, I'm getting:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Invalid table database.with.dot.Table
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getDbTableName(Utilities.java:2350)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getDbTableName(Utilities.java:2336)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1070)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1058)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.loadDynamicPartitions(Hive.java:1581)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.Shim_v1_2.loadDynamicPartitions(HiveShim.scala:823)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadDynamicPartitions$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveClientImpl.scala:689)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadDynamicPartitions$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:687)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$loadDynamicPartitions$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:687)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(HiveClientImpl.scala:283)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.liftedTree1$1(HiveClientImpl.scala:230)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.retryLocked(HiveClientImpl.scala:229)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.withHiveState(HiveClientImpl.scala:272)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.loadDynamicPartitions(HiveClientImpl.scala:687)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadDynamicPartitions$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:796)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadDynamicPartitions$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:784)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$loadDynamicPartitions$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:784)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:95)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.loadDynamicPartitions(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:784)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:268)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.sideEffectResult(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:170)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.InsertIntoHiveTable.doExecute(InsertIntoHiveTable.scala:347)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:132)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:113)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:87)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:263)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.insertInto(DataFrameWriter.scala:243)
  ... 46 elided
```

Are there any ways to use Spark to insert into a Hive table whose database name has dots in it?

Edit: I am able to query from the table using either Hive shell or Spark SQL, just not insert back into the table.

Comment: Why would you want to have a dot in your database name?

Comment: And first of all, how did you created a databases name with a dot. I think hive dont allow to create a database name with a dot. Please clarify the creation method.

Comment: check this HIve JIRA, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10120

Comment: @lev, legacy code, our database just had dots in them

Comment: @Amit, Hive only disallows dots in column names, not db.

Comment: @RongzhouShen can you please help me with the statement whichcan create a database name with a dot. In hive cli, i tried all the combinations and i am not able to create the database with dot in its name. It always says FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. InvalidObjectException(message:amit.test is not a valid database name)